# Howto create a transparent https proxy with firehol and tinyproxy?

Tags: transparent-proxy, tinyproxy

I have a transparent proxy setup in Ubuntu 10.04.4 with firehol and tinyproxy that works fine for http but I can't get it to work for https.

Connecting to tinyproxy directly works fine as the following commands complete ok:

```
env  http_proxy=localhost:8888 curl  http://www.google.com
env https_proxy=localhost:8888 curl https://www.google.com
```

Http transparent proxying also works fine:

```
curl  http://www.google.com
```

but when accessing google directly using https, the command just hangs:

```
curl  https://www.google.com
```

Here are the complete config files for firehol and tinyproxy. Note that I have no interest in using firehol for anything but transparent proxying.

firehol.conf:

```
transparent_proxy "80 443" 8888 proxy
interface any world
   client all accept
   server all accept
```

tinyproxy.conf (all defaults except upstream proxy):

```
User    nobody
Group   nogroup
Port    8888
Timeout 600
DefaultErrorFile  "/usr/share/tinyproxy/default.html"
StatFile          "/usr/share/tinyproxy/stats.html"
Logfile           "/var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log"
LogLevel Info
PidFile           "/var/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid"
MaxClients     100
MinSpareServers  5
MaxSpareServers 20
StartServers    10
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"
ConnectPort 443
ConnectPort 563
upstream corporate.fire.wall:8080
```

Comment: Another option here is writing some code in Go to do the same. `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` in the stdlib does what you want, and you can always modify it if you want to proxy to multiple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell tinyproxy simply does not support incoming HTTPS connections.  It will permit you to access HTTPS sites by using the **CONNECT** method, but for that to be used, the browser/client must know that it is talking to a proxy server, and use the correct connection methods.

The `ConnectPort` directives simply defines which ports it is permissible to make connections to.

The only FOSS product that supports transparently proxying HTTPS connection is [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump), and the support for that is relatively recent.  In also introduces some pretty major security concerns since a transparent HTTPS proxy has to perform a man-in-the-middle attack and decrypt the connection so that it knows what to connect to.

Comment: That makes sense. After investigating, it appears that you are correct and squid is the way to go. There is no backport of 3.1 with ssl/https support available for Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) so custom compile is required. I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: With Squid version 3.5 it is now possible to use "peek and splice" feature to implement HTTPS proxy without doing man-in-the-middle (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice).

Comment: Transparent https indeed not supported by Tinyproxy: https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/88

Comment: Wouldn't `mitmproxy` work as an https proxy solution? It's designed for this purpose. No matter what solution you use, you will have to add a custom cert to your root store.

Comment: @1110101001 haven't tried that, but it seems likely that it could work . No idea if mitmporxy would have met the other requirements the OP might have had ~11 years ago.